# Async - React Select with redux doesn't load the options on time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-select

I am trying to use an async react-select with redux but it is not working correctly.
I set `options` from mapStateToProps and it is updated by function `getPlaces()`.

After `getPlaces()` is called which is inside of `getOptions()`, `options`state itself is updated but `options`which is callback in `getOptions()` takes the previous value.

Here is the code.

**searchForm.js**

```
import { getPlaces, options } from '../../action/searchActions';


const SearchForm = ({getPlaces, options}) => {
console.log(options) // this is updated on time

const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

const handleInputChange = (newValue: string) => {
    const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, '');
    setInputValue(inputValue);
    return inputValue;
};

const getOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
    if (!inputValue) {
      return callback([]);
    }

    getPlaces(inputValue)
    .then(result=>{
        console.log(options)// this shows the previous value
        callback(options);
    })
  };

return (
    <div className="search-form-container">
        <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <div className="row">
                <AsyncSelect
                  cacheOptions
                  loadOptions={getOptions}
                  defaultOptions
                  labelKey="PlaceName"
                  onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                  filterOption={() => (true)}
                  className="col-md-3"
                />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    options: state.search.options
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getPlaces})(SearchForm);
```

**searchActions.js**

```
export const getPlaces = (query) => async dispatch => {
try{
    const places = await axios({
        url: `/places?query=${query}`,
        method: 'GET',
    })

    const places_data = places.data.Places;
    const change_places_format = (places_data) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const new_format_places = places_data.map(place => {
                return {
                    ...place,
                    value: place.PlaceId,
                    label: place.PlaceName += ` — ${place.CountryName}  (${place.PlaceId.replace('-sky', '')})`
                }
            })
            resolve(new_format_places)
        });
    }

    const modified_places = await change_places_format(places_data);
    await dispatch({
        type: GET_PLACES,
        payload: modified_places
    })
}catch(err){
    dispatch({
        type: PLACES_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.statusText
    })
}       
}
```

**searchReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    options: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_PLACES:
            return{
                ...state,
                options: action.payload,
            }
    default: 
        return state;
    }
}
```

I have gone through the many similar questions I have not found the answer.
Can anyone find what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it makes sense that renders the same value - you will get the new options from your store _in the next render_ because the prop changes and causes a new cycle of rendering. That's where you should be expecting your new values to come from, and render again

Comment: @Gonzalo.-Thank you for your answer. So is it not possible to get ```options``` as prop from the store?